# explain the comma separated for expression

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to track down a bug in the ember.js source code when I came across this for loop:

```
for (operationIndex = rangeStart = 0, len = this._operations.length; operationIndex < len; rangeStart = rangeEnd + 1, ++operationIndex) {
```

The constituent parts are broken down to what looks like multiple declarations, e.g.:

```
operationIndex = rangeStart = 0, len = this._operations.length
```

Can anyone explain what this declaration does and can I assume that the loop counter is initilaized to 0 given the above expression?

Comment: Isn't it quite obvious? "[`The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)"

Comment: If it was quite obvious, I would not have posted the question

Comment: @Teemu, not "second", "last" operand..

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, all correct) Simple second comma operators operand may be another comma expression))

Comment: The comma operator has nothing to do with the assignments here, both operands are evaluated independently, and the value returned by comma operator is not used anywhere, it goes straight to the bit space. Notice, that there are no declarations in the expression, only assignments. Please check this simple demo at [jsFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F73Pk/2/). What comes to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), comma has the lowest precedence of all operators in JS.

Answer (score -1):

Taking this "template":

```
for (A; B; C)
```

There are three parts in the loop declaration. The first part (A) is executed once before the actual loop begins, and is usually used to declare the loop iterator but can be used for other things.

The second part (B) is the stop condition: it's being evaluated in the beginning of each iteration, and when returning *false*, the loop ends.

The third part (C) is executed in the end of each iteration and usually used to change the loop iterator so the loop will end at some point.

To focus again on your specific question, the comma is just used to separate two variable assignments.

Comment: I answered the question in the last sentence, consider the rest a background. The return value of the comma operator is not relevant in this case as you're not using it. You asked what the comma is doing and it's answered here, really no idea what else you want.